# Can I send HTTP request and receive response from and to AirConsole API?

Tags: godot, airconsole

Maybe it's possible but I'm not sure what's the URL from reading the [Unity plugin source code](https://github.com/AirConsole/airconsole-unity-plugin/tree/master/Assets/AirConsole/scripts) since I'm not familiar with Unity.

Comment: Please specify a bit more about what you want to achieve. Do you want to build an AirConsole game with godot?

Comment: Yeah, I wanna send an event in Godot every time a function like `onConnect` is called but setting `airconsole.onConnect = godotFunction` in JS is not really possible.